# Are there any JSON pretty-printers that take extra care to be concise?

Tags: javascript, json, line, word-wrap, pretty-print

I'd like a JSON pretty printer that would recognize when an array or object fits on one line and just do that. Example:

```
{
  "fits": ["JSON", "pretty", "printer"],
  "longer": [
    "???????????????????????????????????????????????????",
    "???????????????????????????????????????????????????",
    "???????????????????????????????????????????????????",
    "???????????????????????????????????????????????????",
    "???????????????????????????????????????????????????"
  ]
}
```

Is there a standalone library like this? If not, how would I go about writing one?

I'm most interested in a JavaScript implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any such concise JSON printer, but it shouldn't be hard to make your own if you want to:

- You can use the `for(property in object)` to iterate over the properties of a given object.

  - Depending on use case, you might want to filter with `hasOwnProperty`.
- You can determine if an reference points to an object, array, string or number with `typeof`
- Have your pretty printer function receive the initial indentation offset and the object to be printed. This might be enough to decide if you should inline each property or not.

  - I'm not sure this "greedy" strategy is always "optimal" - perhaps it might be better to do something in multiple lines now to be able to inline later. I wouldn't worry with this at first though.

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON is primarily a data transport format, I assume that you mean viewing raw JSON in the browser?  If so, then there are a few options:

- [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) - Checks and reformats JSON
- [A pure JS version of the above](http://zaach.github.com/jsonlint/)
- [JSONView for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)
- [Safari JSON Formatter](https://github.com/rfletcher/safari-json-formatter)

You should be able to dig into the source of the last three if you require further customization.  I'd start with iterating through the `value.length` property where `value` is/are the array element(s) to see if you can limit your output to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [replacer function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459#code-snippet-3) to compare the total number of characters in each key/value pair to a fixed length. Here is a simple example:

```
function replacer(key, value)
  {
  var key_arr = [];
  var value_arr = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (_ in value)
    {
    key_arr.push(_);
    value_arr.push(value[_]);
    }
  for(;i < value_arr.length;i++)
    {
    if (key_arr[i].length + value_arr[i].length < 80)
      {
      console.log(key_arr[i] + ":" + "\t" + value_arr[i])
      }
    else
      {
      console.log(key_arr[i] + ":" + "\n" + value_arr[i])
      }
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
var json;

json = {"foo":"1","bar":"2"},      
JSON.stringify(json, replacer, 4);

json = {"foo":"12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890","bar":"2"};

JSON.stringify(json, replacer, 4);
```